# ZF3: How to response a JSON from an action function

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework3

I'm calling to an action function using angular js. I call the action function and receive the parameters correctly, but when I try to response a JsonModel I don't know why Zend Framework responde with a ViewModel. I think because Zend Framework doesn't detect an Ajax call from Angular JS. So, how can a I call to my action function and Zend Framework detects this call like an Ajax call?

**angular js:**

```
self.sendData = function(url, data){
    var promise = $q.defer();
    console.log("Dentro de senDAta!!!");
    var config = {
        headers : {
            "Accept"        :   "application\json",
            "Content-Type"  :   "application\json"
        },
        resposeType : "json"
    };
    $http.post(url, data, config).success(function(response, status, headers, config){
                console.log("dentro de success!!!");
                promise.resolve(response);
            }).error(function(data){
                //Error de sistemas
                console.log("Error en sendData: " + data);
            });
    return promise.promise;        
};
```

**/application/config/module.config.php**

```
return [
    //...

    'view_manager' => [
        //...

        'strategies' => [
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ],
    ],
];
```

**/Controller/LoginController.php**

```
public function loginAction(){
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $log = new \File\LogWriter();
    $log->writeLog(get_class($this) . "::" . __FUNCTION__ . ": Dentro de loginAction()");
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() === true){
        $log->writeLog(get_class($this) . "::" . __FUNCTION__ . ": Llamada hecha por Ajax");
    }else{
        $log->writeLog(get_class($this) . "::" . __FUNCTION__ . ": Llamada no hecha por ajax");
    }
        $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
        $email = $params["email"];
        $password = $params["password"];

        $log->writeLog(get_class($this) . "::" . __FUNCTION__ . ": email: " . $email . " password: " . $password);
        $user = new User($email);
        return new JsonModel([
            "result"    => 0
        ]);             
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution!!! If you want to have the possibility to return a ViewModel or a JsonModel from an action function, you have to follow the next steps in each module of your application where you want to response a ViewModel or a JsonModel

**First:**
In /projectName/module/Application/config/module.config.php

```
return [
    //...

    'view_manager' => [
        //...

        'strategies' => [
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ],
    ],
];
```

**Second:** In /projectName/module/Application/src/Module.php:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // Register a "render" event, at high priority (so it executes prior
    // to the view attempting to render)
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $app->getEventManager()->attach('render', [$this, 'registerJsonStrategy'], 100);
}

public function registerJsonStrategy(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app          = $e->getTarget();
    $locator      = $app->getServiceManager();
    $view         = $locator->get('Zend\View\View');
    $jsonStrategy = $locator->get('ViewJsonStrategy');

    // Attach strategy, which is a listener aggregate, at high priority
    $jsonStrategy->attach($view->getEventManager(), 100);
}
```

Finally, I have to say that the last line of code **$jsonStrategy->attach($view->getEventManager(), 100);** in function registerJsonStrategy(MvcEvent $e) originally was ...

```
$view->getEventManager()->attach($jsonStrategy, 100);
```

You can check this at https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-view/quick-start/#creating-and-registering-alternate-rendering-and-response-strategies

Bur this line of code returns me this error:

> [Sat Apr 29 00:23:53.416382 2017] [:error] [pid 21286] [client
>   127.0.0.1:55362] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Zend\EventManager\EventManager::attach() must be callable,
>   integer given, called in
>   /var/www/html/31juegos/module/Application/src/Module.php on line 63
>   and defined in
>   /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php:185\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/31juegos/module/Application/src/Module.php(63):
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->attach(Object(Zend\View\Strategy\JsonStrategy),
>   100)\n#1
>   /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322):
>   Application\Module->registerJsonStrategy(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))\n#2
>   /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(171):
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))\n#3
>   /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(367):
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))\n#4
>   /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(348):
>   Ze in
>   /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php
>   on line 185

So, I have to change this line of code

```
$view->getEventManager()->attach($jsonStrategy, 100);
```

By this other line of code:

```
$jsonStrategy->attach($view->getEventManager(), 100);
```

And the error is fixed!!!

Hope it helps to someone!!!

Comment: Documentation bug: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/issues/108